# append to change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 forms: **foo**, **bar** and **baz** which contains same set of checkboxes:

```
<form id="foo_form" method="post" action="foo">
  <input class="foo checkbox" id="foo_select_1" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <input class="foo checkbox" id="foo_select_2" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
  <input class="foo checkbox" id="foo_select_3" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="action 1" />
</form>
```

Then I have a function like this:

```
function clone_checkboxes_values(src_form, src_prefix, dst_prefix) {
  $('#' + src_form + ' input:checkbox').change(function() {
     $('#' + dst_prefix + this.id.replace(src_prefix, '')).prop('checked', this.checked);
 });
}
```

which I run:

```
clone_checkboxes_values('foo_form', 'foo_select', 'bar_select');
```

and it makes every checkbox change at **foo** to be copied to **bar**.
I wish to run another call to the `clone_checkboxes_values` to copy changes to **baz** as well (don't overwrite `change(function(){})` but append to it. I have no clue how to make it. Please help.

This is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5a3Jj/) with all prepaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
clone_checkboxes_values('foo_form', 'foo_select', 'baz_select');
```

jQuery doesn't overwrite event handlers by default. In other words, any subsequent call to change() only adds a new event handler to the previous. It works the same for other event binding functions such as click(). The event handlers will be sequentially run in the order they were bound to the event.

In other words, if I theoretically execute the following calls,

```
$(<selector>).bind(<event>, <function1>)
$(<selector>).bind(<event>, <function2>)
```

when `<event>` occurs, `function1` will be executed, then will follow `function2`.

Comment: I didn't know that. So this is jQuery magic behind this.. interesting. Is there a way to overwrite it with jQuery than ? I'm just curious.

Comment: @pawel7318 You can use jQuery's [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) or [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to do any of the following: (1) remove a specific event handler, (2) remove all handlers for particular event, (3) remove all event handlers.

Comment: @JLRishe is right. 
$(<selector>).off(<event>).on(<event>,<new handler>) will wipe out all the previous handlers before binding the new one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've already figured it out. All you need to do is call this:

```
clone_checkboxes_values('foo_form', 'foo_select', 'baz_select');
```

Perhaps it wasn't working because you were missing a `'` before `baz_select`.

http://jsfiddle.net/5a3Jj/1/